# Starting node with v8 profiler enabled from ng start

Tags: node.js, angular, profiling, v8

When starting my application in development mode I see 50% of the CPU is used by **node** executable. I wanted to know if this is something related with my code or something related with how **node** works.

I found a nice response to a similar question here:
[how to debug node.js causing 100% cpu usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167477/how-to-debug-node-js-causing-100-cpu-usage)

But I cannot follow the indicated steps because I'm developing using angular, and angular is started by running `ng serve`.

The documentation of `ng serve` is here: https://angular.io/cli/serve but I can't see anything to send additional parameters to **node**. Even more, if I try to do `ng serve --prof` an error is generated.

What else can I do in order to profile the execution of node.js?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the path of the `ng` script as parameter for the `node` binary like this:

```
node --prof ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve
```